# How to use the NOAA API to query past weather data for a given set of coordinates

Tags: python, r, weather-api, noaa

I am trying to retrieve past NOAA data using latitudinal and longitudinal coordinates. I am interested both in historical time series and annual summaries for variables such as temperature, wind speed, cloud fraction, and precipitation.

EX: 2008-02-20 13:00 in (25.033972, 121.564493)

I hope to automate a process that achieves this for 900,000+ locations. Any ideas? Ideally this script would be written in R or Python.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/python-weather-api/wiki/Examples#NOAA

Answer (score 13):

1. Figure out the [endpoint/dataset](http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/datasets) that contains the information you want (or multiple ones)
2. Convert lat/long into zip code
3. Find the correct station for the zip code [here](http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/search)
4. For each endpoint, pull data for each location.
5. ???
6. Profit???

Answer (score 9):

NOAA is now on its second version of the NOAA web API.  APIs are useful because you can essentially query a web service, using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/http://) and a python `dict` of arguments that describe what you want.  @Cravden has made a nice class that will get you started on [GitHub](https://github.com/crvaden/NOAA_API_v2). NOAA has [nice documentation](https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/webservices/v2) describing what you can get and how (you need to give them and email to get an access token). [Other](http://www.rcc-acis.org/docs_webservices.html#title24) climate data aggregators also do this kind of thing.
Something as simple as this might get you started:

```
import requests


def get_noaa_data(url, data_type, header):

    r = requests.get(url, data_type, headers=header)
    print(r)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    token = 'gotowebsitetorequesttoken'
    creds = dict(token=token)
    dtype = 'dataset'
    url = 'https://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/cdo-web/api/v2/'

    get_noaa_data(url, dtype, creds)
```

If you are going for thousands of places, you might consider downloading gridded data, making a shapefile of the points, then extracting raster values to an attribute table as done [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/46893/getting-pixel-value-of-gdal-raster-under-ogr-point-without-numpy).